# unable to retrieve image from mysql through rest api using java

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

My problem is deceptively simple but I am unable to find the answer. Through Java and JDBI, I am able to retrieve the image from MySQL database and store it locally. But when I try with a rest api, it is giving the error in the attached screenshot. I have searched for this quite a bit but am unable to find a solution.

The stack trace is as below:

```
 Type Exception Report
    Message java.lang.IllegalStateException: No container builder available for java.sql.Blob

    Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

    Exception

    javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No container builder available for java.sql.Blob
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No container builder available for java.sql.Blob
    org.skife.jdbi.v2.ContainerFactoryRegistry.createBuilderFor(ContainerFactoryRegistry.java:73)
    org.skife.jdbi.v2.Query.first(Query.java:271)
    org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.ResultReturnThing$SingleValueResultReturnThing.result(ResultReturnThing.java:110)
    org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.ResultReturnThing.map(ResultReturnThing.java:46)
    org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.QueryHandler.invoke(QueryHandler.java:43)
    org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.SqlObject.invoke(SqlObject.java:212)
    org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.SqlObject$3.intercept(SqlObject.java:127)
    org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.CloseInternalDoNotUseThisClass$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8d85a881.retrieveImage(<generated>)
    com.sample.obs.factory.BooksFactory.retrieveImage(BooksFactory.java:188)
    com.sample.obs.model.Books.listAllBooks(Books.java:378)
    com.sample.obs.util.BooksRest.listAllBooks(BooksRest.java:29)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Adding the rest api and the listAllBooks method below :

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public final Books[] listAllBooks() {
    Books b = new Books();
    Books[] shelf = b.listAllBooks();
    return shelf;
}



public final Books[] listAllBooks() {
    Books[] bList = BooksFactory.listAllBooks();

    for(Books b: bList) {
      String path = "E:\\" + b.getBookId() + ".png";
      Blob imageBlob = BooksFactory.retrieveImage(b.getBookId());

      try {
        byte[] image = handleBlob(imageBlob);
        
        if (image != null) {
          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
          fos.write(image);
          fos.close();

          b.setImageUrl(path);
        } else {
          System.out.println("Image not available");
          b.setImageUrl(null);
        }
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      int avail = BooksFactory.retrieveAvailableCopies(b.getBookId());
      b.setAvailableCopies(avail);
    }
    return bList;
  }
```

The DAO and Factory methods return a Blob and I have a mapper for getting the blob from the DB.

Please guide as to how to solve this.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the full stack trace as text, not an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my issue. I added the below code to the dbi object.

```
dbi.registerContainerFactory(new ContainerFactory<Blob>(){

        @Override
        public boolean accepts(Class<?> arg0) {
          return false;
        }

        @Override
        public ContainerBuilder<Blob> newContainerBuilderFor(Class<?> arg0) {
          return newContainerBuilderFor(arg0);
        }
        
      });
```

I followed the [this](http://www.javased.com/index.php?source_dir=jdbi%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Forg%2Fskife%2Fjdbi%2Fv2%2FContainerFactoryRegistry.java) link for the solution.